# jquery open several pdf in new tabs

Tags: jquery, pdf, browser-tab

I have an array of Strings which are the directoriess of my pdfs such as:

```
var fluids_array = ["Fluid/no1.pdf", "Fluid/no2.pdf"];

for(var i in fluids_array) {
        var fluidplan = fluids_array[i];        

        var myWindow = window.open(fluidplan,"_blank");

        if (myWindow) {
            myWindow.focus();
        }
    }
```

Why does it only opens the last (second) pdf and not both? How can I fix it?

Comment: I have tried same thing but for me only 1st pdf was opening and not 2nd one. Then i noticed that 2nd pdf is blocked by chrome. then i have given the permissions to allow popups and things are working for me now.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your snippet with 2 urls into the array. This code opens correctly both, obviously browser can focus just one window at once.

Some tips if really the first file has not been opened:

- Check if the file actually exists
- Which browser are you using? Probably you should specify an identifier for the opened window, else it could try to open both in the same window or tab. Check this: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_name.asp

Comment: hey hey, i am using chrome and the problem was the chrome-ad-blocker

Comment: @xyzale I have tried without focusing on window. It still opens only one window.

Comment: So strange. I'm using Chrome as well. 
However I had a similar issue. Browsers don't like when windows are opened by js without a direct action from the user. I suggest to find a different solution if you want to be sure all browsers behave as you like.

Comment: same thing working for me @xyzale now previously i was chrome, who was blocking popups. I have just given permission and it working now